# Click on input type fires the form with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When I click the button it works, but when I try to add "quantity" and click the arrows to do it - it immediately runs the function. How do I avoid it?

```
<form ng-click="ctrl.launch(quantity, someOtherInfo)">
     <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" ng-model="quant" ng-init="quant=1" min="1" step="1">
     </div>
     <button class="hit_it_button" >LAUNCH!</button>
</form>
```

I tried to place ng-click right in the button, but it just doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `ng-click` to `ng-submit`.

Here is helpful [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

Answer (score 1):

your script should look like this I think:

```
<form>
 <div class="quantity">
      <input type="number" ng-model="quantity" ng-init="quant=1" min="1" step="1">
 </div>
 <button class="hit_it_button" ng-click="ctrl.launch(quantity)>LAUNCH!</button></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`ngClick`** does not submit the form.You should change ng-click to **`ng-submit`**.

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.launch(quantity, someOtherInfo)">
     <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" ng-model="quant" ng-init="quant=1" min="1" step="1">
     </div>
     <button class="hit_it_button" >LAUNCH!</button>
</form>
```